# Why and when to add element to the end of singly linked list?

Tags: singly-linked-list

Is there any reason to add element to the end of a singly linked list instead of adding to the beginning? Adding to the end you have to traverse the whole list every time so the bigger the list gets the more time it takes to add a new item.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example, if you're keeping the list sorted, you might need to insert your new node at any point, including at the end.

Comment: But wouldn't it be more effective to always add to the beginning but then to sort the whole list at the end if you need?

Comment: Sorting a singly linked list after the fact is a "not fun" process.